# Historical frequency of parenthetical plural(s)

Tags: grammatical-number, punctuation, parenthetical-plural

It seems to me that parenthetical plurals have been increasing in recent years. Is there any way to accurately measure this? Google Ngram Viewer seems like a method, but the use of parentheses, first of all, seems a problem.

Comment: I quite agree with you that  parenthetical plurals do pose an issue. It might be wise of you to provide a context to which you speak.  In general, it would be impossible to measure the usage of parenthetical plurals everywhere however if we were to reduce this possibly the internet or maybe even internet public forums it becomes a bit more plausible to measure.

Comment: The practice has been around for 50 years at least, and I haven't noted any obvious uptick in it's frequency of occurrence.  If anything I see it less often now than 20 years ago.

Comment: @Hot Licks. Ok. So your perception differs from mine. I appreciate your view that the opposite may be the case. But I'm also wondering how either way can be shown with data. Google Ngram seems like a good option, but searching for parentheses seems to be a problem. And maybe a more specific corpus would be better, if available, such as all US Federal documents, since this sort of punctuation seem, to me, most prevalent on those types of documents.

Comment: Ngram has many merits, but the way it processes data makes it technically impossible to use in this case.

Comment: And a "roll-your-own" scan of some document database would likely be rendered bogus if you could not somehow "crack" the syntax of the documents and identify parts of speech, since otherwise you'd very often be led astray by things such as "(s)" appearing as a footnote identifier.

Comment: The Corpus of Historical American English (COHA) at BYU may allow the kind of searches needed.  The time period covered is from c1800.  I haven't used them since they "improved" their user interface.

Comment: @DCDuring, you can search for parenthetical plurals after nouns by inputting "[nn*] ( s )". And you can restrict to look at various periods. But you have to figure out a way to factor out the noise from *non*-parenthetical plural occurrences of "(s)". And even after factoring out the noise, the data might not be robust enough to form a reliable picture...

Comment: Can you give a few examples of this in? Is this in a sentence or only a phrase? What kinds of documents do you find it in?

Comment: Ngram has as many demerits too.  One of the traps in using ngrams to divine the popularity of people, ideas, or concepts is that a book only appears once—whether it’s been read once or millions of times. The Lord of the Rings is in there once, and so is some random paper on mechanics. The two texts are weighted equally. It doesn’t reflect what is people are talking about so much as what people are publishing about—and until very recently, most people didn’t have access to publishing. Like, what does this really tell you about language? Ngram is anecdotal and cannot be taken at face value.

Answer (score 1):

While total usage of the world may be a problem to identify, if you are doing this for a class or a paper, then I suggest that you limit your scope.

Keep the scope to something specific and historical, something that isn't increasing exponentially like the 'net or StackExchange, something like the New York Times, USA Today, Washington Post, National Geographic, or a "Journal" for a field you are in.

If one of these, or something similar has a full database and it is searchable, you should be able to get an answer that isn't based simply on availability or population increase.

Comment: "Increasing exponentially" means the rate of change is positive and proportional to its current value---which is certainly not the case for the text of standard newspapers and journals you mentioned. It could possibly be true for StackExchange or the internet, but only for a short time. If the proportion is very small, it is almost impossible to tell if growth is exponential, except over a long time period. Conclusion: be very careful about using terms related to exponential growth.

Comment: @DavidHandelman Mathematically speaking, exponential change is when change is calculated using a exponent.  Like x squared.  Exponent of two.  Proportional change is multiplicative.  Like 2 times x.  Exponential change graphs as a curve.  The slope of the derivative line is the exponent.  Proportional change graphs as a straight line.  The slope is the proportion.  Sorry, you triggered the math geek in me.

Comment: @Xaloruous *Absolutely wrong.* This is what comes of using a technical term without knowing its meaning. Your example,  x^2, is quadratic growth, and certainly not exponential. Exponential growth (look it up) is much faster, and as I said, occurs when the *rate of change* is proportional to the current amount. The rate of change [as x increases] of x^2  is only 2x, which for large x is infinitesimal compared to x^2.